# can hackers access a subnet in different network?

Tags: network, exploit, vulnerability

If I'm in my private network with my IP 192.168.4.5 and public IP 34.124.x.x, can hackers access my computer only with exploit/vulnerability (no malware) from a different network? The videos, sites and books all have examples with private IPs.

Comment: It depends on the configuration of the involved routers.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking weather or not an attacker on the WAN side of your NAT router can initiate a connection to a host on the LAN side of your router.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8772/how-important-is-nat-as-a-security-layer and the questions linked from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176744/why-is-nat-referred-to-as-the-poor-mans-firewall for some interesting reading on this subject.